# Как добавить плавности?

Tags: javascript

Вот есть код аккордеона:

```
$(document).ready(function(jQuery){
//accordeon
   $("li:has(ul.dropdown)").addClass("dropdownLi")
   $("li.dropdownLi > a").click(function(eventObject){return false})
$(function() {
    $("a").bind('click',function() {
        var _this = $(this);

_this.toggleClass('selected', 2);
_this.next().toggleClass('dropdown', 200);
// Ïðîõîäèì ïî äðóãèì ññûëêàì è âûêëþ÷àåì àêòèâíîå ñîñòîÿíèå
   $("a").not(_this).each(function() {
      $(this).next().addClass('dropdown', 200);
      $(this).removeClass('selected', 2);
});
});
});
});
```

Не пойму, откуда берется задержка где-то в 3 секунды, прежде чем отк./скрыть.
И как добавить сюда плавное открывание?

Comment: Используйте `$.slideDown(), $.slideUp(), $.toggleSlide()`

Comment: изучение только начато скриптов, если не сложно покажите как это сделать